# Does defining variables as "locally" as possible make the implementation faster?

Tags: java, performance, coding-style

While programming, I often come across the following scenario (described in code). I define variables in the block that they are going to be used.

```
    int maximumLengthOfToken = 0;

    while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
    {
       String line; // definition
       line = fileScanner.nextLine();

       Scanner lineScanner; // definition
       lineScanner = new Scanner(line);

       String token = lineScanner.next(); // definition and assignment
       if(stringToMatch.endsWith(token))
        {
                 if(token.length() >= maximumLengthOfToken )
                  {
                     maximumLengthOfToken = token.length();  
                     builder.append(line);
                     builder.append("\n\n\n");
                  }
        }
    }
    fileScanner.close();
```

However, sometimes, for the sake of "neatness" and also because I come from a C background, I like to define all variables at the top, regardless of where they are used. So I do the following -

```
    int maximumLengthOfToken = 0;
    String line; // definition
    Scanner lineScanner; // definition
    String token; // definition

    while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
    {
       line = fileScanner.nextLine();
       lineScanner = new Scanner(line);

       token = lineScanner.next(); // definition

               if(stringToMatch.endsWith(token))
                {
                 if(token.length() >= maximumLengthOfToken )
                  {
                     maximumLengthOfToken = token.length();  
                     builder.append(line);
                     builder.append("\n\n\n");
                  }
        }
    }
    fileScanner.close();
```

"Ah! It looks so neat", I think.

However, does this have any effect on the performance of the code? Would the first style lead to faster executing code or the second style? Also, what is the convention in such cases? I believe it is the first style.

Comment: The compiler is likely to observe that these are equivalent, and thus compile them to identical bytecode.

Comment: Would garbage collection make a speed difference here, assuming the compiler doesn't pick up on the semantic equivalency and thus doesn't optimize the first piece of code?

Comment: You should consider declaring variables where they are first used. It makes the code easier to reason by another person. There's nothing worse than see a bunch of variable declaration at the top and having to mentally track them all. Also see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/56585

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  There will be no performance difference.

If you doubt this, ask yourself, "Will it take longer for the computer to look up my variable if it's 2000 bytes away, than it will if it's 200 bytes or 20 bytes away?"  The answer should be no.

The only case where it *might* make a difference is if your variable drops out of the processor cache [(see locality)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) before it gets used, in which case moving the variable closer to where it is being used *might* improve speed.  But it would take a lot of code between the variable and its use for that to happen.

It is also possible that the compiler will compile your method down to the same bytecode anyway.  In short, I think you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: +1 for the link on locality of reference and the (implicit) mention of optimizing compilers.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, there's no significant performance difference.

You want to choose between putting variable declarations at the top of your method, and putting them near where they are used.  Don't force yourself into that choice.  You can have both - by making your methods very short.  When you find yourself faced with this choice, treat it as your code telling you: "your methods are too long."

Shorter methods are easier to write, easier to test, easier to debug, easier to maintain.  If you have no method over (say) 10 lines, you'll never face this problem - and you'll have better organized code.

Answer (score 1):

This probably doesn't have any effect on the performance of the code -- I would expect that the generated bytecode was the same -- but the first version is generally considered more maintainable and readable.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case there could be a slight (or sometimes even dramatic) difference, but in the case of Java very likely not, for the standard compiler chain.

Where compilers might tend to differ is where you have "varA" defined in one range and "varB" defined in a disjoint range.  The compiler may observe the ranges are disjoint and assign the same stack slot to both, which very, very slightly improves interpreter performance.  But, perversely, this technique can cause worse optimization in a JITC, if it isn't smart enough to figure out what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the use of runtime optimization in modern Java implementations you should not see much of a difference. Therefore, you should focus mainly on clarity and ease of maintenance.

That said, there a few good reasons to declare variables as closely to the location of use as possible:

- It is easier to read, especially with very short lived (e.g. temporary) variables. The reader can immediately see the type of the variable, without having to scroll up to the start of the method.
- By limiting the scope of variables as much as possible you reduce the probability of inadvertent errors when e.g. reusing a loop counter.
- Some optimizations such as escape analysis may perform better when variables have as limited a scope as possible.

As a sidenote, I program in both C and Java and it *is* occasionally difficult to context-switch from one to the other. Using C-style conventions in Java (or vice-versa), though, is not a very good idea. C conventions are dictated by limitations that Java simply does not have - using them only makes your code harder for others to read.

Answer (score 0):

The largest 'performance' difference regarding the scope of the variable will be in garbage collection.  Declaring the variable locally may potentially allow unused variables to be collected by the GC sooner.